# UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a timer which calls the below code to reload a cell in the second section of my grouped UITableView. It works perfectly fine unless I scroll the screen up so that the first section/cell cannot be seen. Once it "springs back" to its correct position, I see that the text which should appear in section 0 has appeared in section 1 and vice-versa.

```
  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Does reloadRowsAtIndexPaths or cellForRowAtIndex path work from the top of the full (visible or invisible) cells, or does it only work starting on the cells that are visible on the screen? In other words, does section 0 actually change depending whether it is visible on-screen or not?

What else would cause cellForRowAtIndexPath to load the wrong data into the cells?

Comment: As you may know, the cell are recycled, and when you use a recycled cell, it has older content set. Maybe that is your problem, be sure to reset all the cell content to avoid showing content of another cell.

Comment: @Raspu: How would you do that exactly?

Comment: Every time a cell must be shown, the table view calls the method ´tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:´ from it delegate. In this method you must return a cell, and to avoid overloading, you use ´dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:´ to reuse a cell that is not being shown right now. Make sure that you always change the label text (if you are using the standar cell, that is ´cell.textLabel.text´) for that cell.

Comment: @Raspu: I've tried setting cell.textLabel.text for all sections.. If I don't do anything tricky (such as code for adding subViews with a button) then it behaves itself. Perhaps the problem is related to something like this :     CGRect cellFrame = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; ..perhaps this is getting the wrong frame when its being scrolled? (I am updating a cell with a timer every second, so perhaps that is my problem?)

Comment: Can you post your code? The cellForRowAtIndexPath, and the one that's fired with the NSTimer?

Comment: @Raspu: Hi, I've squashed my project down into something smaller. If you try this: http://www.mediafire.com/?o601abdhaothxs5 You will find that scrolling the screen up and holding it there for a second or 2 will result in 2 OK buttons being added.. I don't know why.. Also noticed that the correct OK button flashes once (disappears) as well. Its an Xcode 4 project.

Comment: I fixed both of your problems, check my answer, also, could you add the relevant part of your code to make the question useful to another users? If you want, I can edit your question and add it.

Comment: Where you able to fix it by your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I played a bit with your project, here are my suggestions:

As you are adding the button to the cell, remember to remove it when you don't want use it (when you refresh the cell, basically you create a new cell, and store the second one to reuse, so if you scroll down and then up, you'll reuse that cell as the cell for the name).

```
  if (cell == nil) 
  {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }  
 [[cell viewWithTag:2] removeFromSuperview];
```

for this to work, you must set the corresponding tag to the button:

```
  myButton1.tag = 2;
  [cell addSubview:myButton1];
```

And also, add the button directly to the cell, not to the contentView (this just worked for me, I'm not sure why).

**EDIT**: I uploaded a fixed version of your project, [download it](http://bit.ly/LOcoZL).

Comment: Also, always use cell.textLabel.text to set the labels, cell.text is deprecated.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much for your help. Its been over a week or so since I've had the chance to use the Mac but I'm going to get back into it now. Awesome, thanks!